# Slick slider and hamburger menu conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, hamburger-menu

I'm attempting to achieve a carousel effect on a page utilizing a hamburger menu for a responsive design project, but cannot get them to play nice together. If I set up separate pages for each, they work flawlessly, but in combination, one or the other will work, but not both. I've been searching for and trying various solutions, but to no avail. I suspect the issue is related to jQuery/js .

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
    setting-name: setting-value
  });
});

$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
}); 

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.main_h').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

// Mobile Navigation
$('.mobile-toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').addClass('open-nav');
    }
});

$('.main_h li a').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.navigation').removeClass('open-nav');
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    }
});

// navigation scroll lijepo radi materem
$('nav a').click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var offset = 70;
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works for my menu but not the slider. Whereas, when rearranged, the following allows the slider to work, but not the menu:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.main_h').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

// Mobile Navigation
$('.mobile-toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').addClass('open-nav');
    }
});

$('.main_h li a').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.navigation').removeClass('open-nav');
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    }
});

// navigation scroll lijepo radi materem
$('nav a').click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var offset = 70;
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});

    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
      $(".center").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
      $(".variable").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: true
      });
      $('.responsive').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
    }
  ]
});
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried using different sliders including one which was strictly CSS without any success. Is it possible to resolve this conflict and use these features together? I am at a loss.

12/30 edit
@Matt Oestreich
Still trying to figure this out. I tried updating jQuery and adding "no conflict" still without resolving the issue:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $(".responsive").slick({
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is so much code... I think your best bet is to go ahead and create a Stack Snippet that shows the issue you are having.. This way it is easier for people to see what your issue is versus having to read through a ton of code (not to mention increases your odds at getting an answer)...

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I zeroed in on the issue.

Comment: Happy you got it resolved.

Comment: ...would you mind posting your answer here, though? That way it helps someone else that has the same issue as you?

Comment: Not resolved, yet. I took your advice and edited the code down to the section which I believe is causing the conflict between the menu and slider... "zeroed in". Is that what you meant by a "stack snippet"?